# Is it possible to use AddEventListener to add a listener for the hover/enter event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I am trying to add an event listener to respond to hovering over a div and changing its color.

I have to use `addEventListener` ...this is an assignment. I am not sure how that would be possible though?

Like I can use it like this:

```
myButtonItem.addEventListener("click",myrespondfunction,false)
```

to assign a click event handler to myButtonItem...but there is no `"hover"` that I can put in place of `click`.

Comment: You're going to have to add quite a bit more detail here if you expect an answer.

Comment: It's a generic question... lol

Comment: What have you done to try to solve the problem? What do you have so far? Do you know how to create a `div`? Do you know how to apply style to a `div`?

Comment: Yes yes, I know all these things. Already have the div set up everything works. Also have other event handlers (click). Just dont know how to do the hover

Comment: What artificial constraint has been placed such that you can't use the proper solution? **And why have you changed your question?**

Comment: Voting to close as "Not a real question" because "It's difficult to tell what's being asked here."

Comment: @antonpug, please invest some time when asking questions to make sure that they're worded in an unambiguous way so that we can help you to find an answer.

Comment: Guys, the question is homework, so the OP is a student. Don't blast him for not being an expert. The question is poorly worded because the person asking doesn't know the terminology, not because he's a jerk that you should all troll.  Take it easy?

Comment: @Eonasdan: I'll remember that one. :)

Comment: *"Don't blast him for not being an expert."* @Chris: Don't make unfounded accusations. This has nothing to do with not being an expert, nor with not knowing terminology. The original question had very little info, which consisted of only the first two sentences. Then the *"Like I can use it like this:"* part was added after we commented, and so I gave the solution in a comment, to which I received the mere reply of *"...cannot"*. It is a matter of basic communication. Oh, and then after that he changed to question to something entirely different.

Comment: ...not to mention that this user has asked **47 question**. By now he should know how to ask a question appropriately.

Comment: Look at you, in full-on debate mode. I am not here to debate you. I see what was said, and I know what it means, so your explanation was rather superfluous. All I am suggesting is that you could (and, IMO, ought to) cut the guy some slack, purhaps relax a little. Or don't, it doesn't affect me.

Comment: I say we shall delegate this question to Stackoverflow support...seems to be getting heavily political. But really I have noticed one thing about the SO community...people are jerks and rate down questions that they don't understand. Just because you don't get it...doesn't mean it is a bad question.

Comment: @Chris: *"you could...cut the guy some slack"*. I did. I took my time, asked for clarification, gave a solution. I received a discourteous *"...cannot"* in response. The only one acting inappropriately here is antonpug.

Comment: antonpug: *"I say we shall delegate this question to Stackoverflow support"* Sure, why not. The site has standards. Read the faq. If you hover your mouse over the down arrow, you'll see an explanation that justifies the votes you've received. It is your responsibility to ask good and appropriate questions. It is ours to use the tools of the site to rate those questions. I have more confidence than @Chris apparently does in your ability to do better than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish hover effects. The best way is to use CSS selectors:

```
.myDiv {
    background-color: red;
}
.myDiv:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

... a div with the class `myDiv` would show a green background when the mouse enters the div.

A second approach is to use javascript, though this is an extreme overkill for simply changing the background color, considering that the `:hover` pseudo-selector is available and widely supported.

The events you have to choose from are:

**mouseenter** - Fired when the mouse enters an element. Does not bubble, not currently supported by Firefox, Safari, or Chrome, [though it is in the spec and has been for some time](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mouseenter).

**mouseleave** - Fired when the mouse leaves an element. Does not bubble, not currently supported by Firefox, Safari, or Chrome, [though it is in the spec and has been for some time](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mouseleave).

**mouseover** - Fired when the mouse enters an element, bubbles to parent elements

**mouseout** - Fired when the mouse leaves element, bubbles to parent elements

Check out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html for more information about specific quirks related to these events. Because of the weight associated with multiple event handlers (that's why it isn't recommended to use javascript to handle something that CSS can handle... you're adding unnecessary weight to the page), you may want to consider using event delegation to handle these events.  See http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/ for an entry-level article explaining the concept and examining some of the pros and cons. If the plan is to add this to all `a` tags on the page, for example, I would use delegation without question.

As far as actually adding the events, `addEventListener` is not cross-browser. See the article http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html for information on the issue, and the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) which discusses the different and offers cross-browser workaround approaches.